# Showing page based on operating system with NSIS

Tags: directory, nsis, operating-system

I'm working on an NSIS script in which I have two directory pages. One gets the directory for the program install, and one gets the directory for putting any data.

The reason for this, is that with some of the control issues in windows 7 and vista involving the Program Files folder, I want the data to be placed outside of the Program Files folder but still give the user the option to put it where they want.

I have the version plugin for NSIS, and I understand how to use that. My issue is that when someone is installing on XP or earlier I don't want to give them the options for the data.

How can I show a directory page based on what OS the user is running?

Comment: I know I could allow the user to choose no matter what, however, on the my end, the way the product I am working on is set up, it is much easier not having to worry about this scenario if I don't have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To skip a page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Skipping_Pages), call the abort instruction in the pre callback function for the page you want to skip.

I'd also like to point out that even though most users are admin on 2000/XP, that same permission issue exists on any NT based platform, not just Vista+.

Comment: Heh, I'm well aware of that, I'm just a lowly intern doing what I'm told though. Thanks!